# Determining whether a Schur complement is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, schur-complement, block-matrices

Consider the symmetric matrix

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
      A   &  B \\ 
      B^T & -C
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A \in \cal{R}^{n \times n}$ and $C \in \cal{R}^{m\times m}$ are symmetric, positive semidefinite, highly sparse matrices.

Is there an efficient way of checking if the Schur complement

$$S = A + BC^{-1}B^T$$

is invertible by looking at the properties of matrices $M$, $A$, $B$, $C$?

Inverting $C$ is expensive and the inverse of a sparse matrix is a full matrix, which is undesirable.

Thank you all.

Comment: if $n$ is much smaller than $m$, it would be more efficient to instead invert $A$, and find if $S$ is invertible by means of the identity ${\rm det}\,S={\rm det}(C+B^T A^{-1}B){\rm det}(A)/{\rm det}(C)$

Comment: While computing the full inverse $C^{-1}$, for the purpose of later using it in matrix multiplication, is expensive, it should be less expensive to computer the product $D = C^{-1} B^T$, by directly solving the linear system $CD = B^T$. Though, that may depend on the size of $B^T$. Then, use $S = A + BD$.